# MediaWiki 1.16: Section transclusion

Tags: mediawiki

How can I include a single section from one wikipage to another as a reference?

I use a completely new MediaWiki (1.16.5) installation without any extensions. The syntax I use to solve the task is the following: {{:otherPage|sectionName}} I have also used {{:otherPage#sectionName}} but it doesn't work for me too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite what you want, but there is the [Labeled Section Transclusion](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLabeled_Section_Transclusion) extension. AFAIK there is no way to include just any section.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I had already seen the labeled section transclusion before write my question. Well, I don't want to install any extension to have such features if they are available from the box.

Do you know any better place to ask my question?

Comment: You could try [wikitech-l](https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/wikitech-l) or #mediawiki@freenode.net.

Comment: Ok. I'll try ro find the answer there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there's just one section that you want, then `<onlyinclude></onlyinclude>` tags will produce the desired effect. Wrap them around the section in question and then transclude the whole page normally (`{{:otherpage}}`). Only the section in `<onlyinclude>` tags will be transcluded.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
Wrap the text you want transcluded on the other page in the tag. It will not affect the display.